# Скрипт вк отправки сообщения + в чс тех кто отписался, помогите?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

помогите пожалуйста доделать скрипт. Дело в том, когда меня кто то удаляет из друзей, то я на них "подписан" а этот скрипт смотрит на кого я подписан, и если кто то есть здесь, то пишет сообшение и сразу же кидает в ЧС. Проблема в том, что даже если я кину заяву в Друзья кому то, то он напишет тому человеку и кинет в ЧС...) Помогите пожалуйста, как можно его улучшить?

Сам код:

````
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен') #можно получить на vkhost.github.io
    api = vk_session.get_api()
        
    try:
        while True:
            get = api.friends.getRequests(out=1, count=1)
            check = get['count']
            if check == 0:
                pass
            else:
                id = get['items']
                api.messages.send(user_id=id, message='Во дурной', v='5.103')
                api.friends.delete(user_id=id)
                api.account.banUser(user_id=id)
                print(f'Отписался и забанил {id}')
                time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
main() ```
````

Comment: Как вариант сохраняйте список ваших друзей локально и сверяйтесь с ним, сделать проверку числился ли человек на которого подписаны в друзьях, если нет, то ничего не делать, если да, то отправлять сообщение и блокировать

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы сохранялись в файл, ид друзей, при этом не удалялись предыдущие? Чтобы если удался кто то, то он не удалился для сверки